# glClipPlane - Is there an equivalent in webGL?

Tags: three.js, opengl-es-2.0, webgl, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I have a 3D mesh. Is there any possibility to render the sectional view (clipping) like `glClipPlane` in OpenGL?

I am using Three.js r65.

The latest shader that I have added is:
**Fragment Shader:**

```
uniform float time;
uniform vec2 resolution; 
varying vec2 vUv; 
void main( void ) 
{ 
vec2 position = -1.0 + 2.0 * vUv; 
float red = abs( sin( position.x * position.y + time / 2.0 ) ); 
float green = abs( cos( position.x * position.y + time / 3.0 ) ); 
float blue = abs( cos( position.x * position.y + time / 4.0 ) ); 
if(position.x > 0.2  && position.y > 0.2 ) 
{  
discard; 
 } 
gl_FragColor = vec4( red, green, blue, 1.0 ); }
```

**Vertex Shader:**

```
varying vec2 vUv;
void main() 
{ 
vUv = uv;
vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 ); 
gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition; 
}
```

Comment: Did you find any satisfactory solution? I faced [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28046264/1697459).

Comment: Not yet. Still I am having doubt.

Comment: Now there is native support for such functionality in three.js. Check my answer below!

Comment: The question is misleading. If you're looking to find a Three.js answear please specify that on the question. WebGL !=== three.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the newer versions (> r.76) of three.js clipping is supported in the [`THREE.WebGLRenderer`](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Renderers/WebGLRenderer). There [is an array property called `clippingPlanes`](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Renderers/WebGLRenderer.clippingPlanes) where you can add your custom clipping planes (`THREE.Plane` instances).

For three.js you can check these two examples:

**1)** **[WebGL clipping](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_clipping.html)** (code base [here on GitHub](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_clipping.html))

**2)** **[WebGL clipping advanced](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_clipping_advanced.html)** (code base [here on GitHub](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_clipping_advanced.html))

---

### A simple example

To add a clipping plane to the `renderer` you can do:

```js
var normal = new THREE.Vector3( -1, 0, 0 );
var constant = 0;
var plane = new THREE.Plane( normal, constant );
renderer.clippingPlanes = [plane];
```

**[Here a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wilt/m8ysmpm2/)** to demonstrate this.

---

You can also clip on object level by adding a clipping plane to the object material. For this to work you have to set the renderer `localClippingEnabled` property to true.

```js
// set renderer
renderer.localClippingEnabled = true;

// add clipping plane to material
var normal = new THREE.Vector3( -1, 0, 0 );
var constant = 0;
var color = 0xff0000;
var plane = new THREE.Plane( normal, constant );
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: color });
material.clippingPlanes = [plane];
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
```

---

**Note:** In r.77 some of the clipping functionality in the `THREE.WebGLRenderer` was moved moved to a separate `THREE.WebGLClipping` class, check [here for reference in the three.js master branch](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/renderers/webgl/WebGLClipping.js).

Answer (score 11):

Unfortunately in the OpenGL-ES specification against which WebGL has been specified there are no clip planes and the vertex shader stage lacks the `gl_ClipDistance` output, by which plane clipping is implemented in modern OpenGL.

However you can use the fragment shader to implement per-fragment clipping. In the fragment shader test the position of the incoming fragment against your set of clip planes and if the fragment does not pass the test `discard` it.

#### Update

Let's have a look at how clip planes are defined in fixed function pipeline OpenGL:

> ```
> void ClipPlane( enum p, double eqn[4] );
> ```
>
> The value of the first argument, p, is a symbolic constant,CLIP PLANEi, where i is
>   an integer between 0 and n − 1, indicating one of n client-defined clip planes. *eqn*
>   is an array of four double-precision floating-point values. These are the coefficients
>   of a plane equation in object coordinates: p1, p2, p3, and p4 (in that order). The
>   inverse of the current model-view matrix is applied to these coefficients, at the time
>   they are specified, yielding
>
> ```
> p' = (p'1, p'2, p'3, p'4) = (p1, p2, p3, p4) inv(M)
> ```
>
> (where M is the current model-view matrix; the resulting plane equation is unde-
>   fined if M is singular and may be inaccurate if M is poorly-conditioned) to obtain
>   the plane equation coefficients in eye coordinates. All points with eye coordinates
>   transpose( (x_e, y_e,z_e, w_e) ) that satisfy
>
> ```
> (p'1, p'2, p'3, p'4)   x_e  ≥ 0
>                       y_e 
>                       z_e 
>                       w_e 
> ```
>
> lie in the half-space defined by the plane; points that do not satisfy this condition
>   do not lie in the half-space.

So what you do is, you add uniforms by which you pass the clip plane parameters p' and add another out/in pair of variables between the vertex and fragment shader to pass the vertex eye space position. Then in the fragment shader the first thing you do is performing the clip plane equation test and if it doesn't pass you discard the fragment.

In the vertex shader

```
in  vec3 vertex_position;
out vec4 eyespace_pos;

uniform mat4 modelview;

void main()
{
    /* ... */
    eyespace_pos = modelview * vec4(vertex_position, 1);
    /* ... */
}
```

In the fragment shader

```
in vec4 eyespace_pos;

uniform vec4 clipplane;

void main()
{
    if( dot( eyespace_pos, clipplane) < 0 ) {
        discard;
    }
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your swift reply. Do you mean, to use Raycasting in Three.js to achieve sectional view?

Comment: @user2118784: Not quite. You can clip primitives on the fragment level, instead of clipping the primitive geometry. You have to write a fragment shader anyway, so the first thing you do is testing if the fragment's position (pass it as a in/out variable from the vertex shader) passes the clip plane condition.

Comment: @user2118784: I just updated my answer with some example code.

Comment: Thank You. I recently updated my shader. Is that right way to achieve the sectional view? How can I achieve sectional view by a plane? i.e 3d object against Plane.

Comment: Hi datenwolf, Is it possible to use clipper.js [http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsclipper/] for Three.js objects for 3D section view? Please send your comments. Thank you.

Comment: @user2118784: clipper.js is meant for offline geometry preprocessing and as far as I can tell does not use GPU acceleration. If your geometry set is small you surely can abuse it, but with only poor performance. You shaders do something, but they don't clip based on a clip plane.

Comment: Thank you. Please suggest me to start with simple example. i.e clip a cube by plane using Three.js or pure WebGL

Comment: Principle's sound. I haven't checked you got details correct.

May eventually be less confusing to send a projected plane as the uniform. Compare it to frag positions directly, rather than comparing non-projected positions & plane.

If I send original positions as vrtx outputs, it tends to be a temporary hack. It usually means I haven't worked something out.

e.g. it may need envelope-scribbles or a web search, to convince yourself of _how_ to project a plane from world- to clip-space, with the same projection that the vertex shader uses.

Comment: I have a clue to add regarding that transformation I mentioned, which is to project three co-planar points into clip space, and that the plane equation you're looking for, in clip-space coordinates, is of the form A.x + B.y + C.z + D.w = 0.

I'm out of time but that should be enough to get you there. The answer's probably simpler than the workings.