# Three.js Clipping and Raycasting

Tags: three.js

I am implementing clipping using the answers here [glClipPlane - Is there an equivalent in webGL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22628186/glclipplane-is-there-an-equivalent-in-webgl).

I have tried both global and per object clipping. My raycaster is intersecting the clipped part of objects. Is there a way to guarantee the raycaster only intersects the visible portion of an object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clipping occurs on the GPU. Normal raycasting occurs on the CPU.

You will have to implement clipping in your raycasting logic at the application level.

An alternative is to use GPU-picking. You will have to invest some time to understand how that works, and if it is appropriate for your use case.

[Here](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_interactive_cubes_gpu.html) is a three.js example of GPU picking.

three.js r.82

Comment: Thank You. I implemented it at the application layer using plane to point distance check.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (renderer.clippingPlanes.length > 0) {  
  objs = objs.filter(function(elem) {  
    return renderer.clippingPlanes.every(function(elem2) {  
      return elem2.distanceToPoint(elem.point) > 0;  
    });  
  });  
}
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, one should always add an explanation to it.

Answer (score 1):

WestLangley's answer is correct, but didn't give me a hint about how I would solve it for my case, so I'm leaving this here for future searchers. In my case, the meshes were clipped by 3 planes. The intersects object has children which each give an intersection point, ordered from closest to farthest, so I just check if the intersection point is on the correct side of all three clipping planes (and therefore visible).

The THREE.Plane method `distanceToPoint(point)` returns the signed distance to the point. Anything that's negative would be on the wrong side of the clipping plane.

```
function onClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    
    var foundMesh = false;
   
    mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;

    raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );

    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children, true );

    if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
        for (var interObj of intersects) {
            var onRightSide = (clippingPlanes[0].distanceToPoint(interObj.point) > 0 &&
                            clippingPlanes[1].distanceToPoint(interObj.point) > 0 &&
                            clippingPlanes[2].distanceToPoint(interObj.point) > 0);
            if (onRightSide) {
                positionTip(clickedPixel, interObj.object.modelName)  // function to do something else
                foundMesh = true;
                break;
            }
};
```